# Get all tables and all columns from a odbc database

Tags: .net, odbc, db-schema

I want to get all "table" names from a OdbcConnection, and for all "table" names I want to recieve all column names.

So I came across the `OdbcConnection.GetSchema()` functionallity. I manges to get all the table names by simply using `connection.GetSchema("Tables")`. But now I want to get the column information for those tables. I noticed `connection.GetSchema("Columns")` will give me columns information, but this only gives it from a random/first (?) "table" in the datasource (using Windows CSV driver), which doesn't help very mutch.

The most  challenging part is, that would have to work with any (most) ODBC drivers. I won't know which underlying datasource will be used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The column schema will return all tables

```
cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns,
       new Object[] { null, null, null, null });
```

Or for a single table

```
cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns,
       new Object[] { null, null, "table1", null });
```

Similarly,

```
columns = cn.GetSchema("Columns");
```

Returns all columns in all tables.

More info: [Schema Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716722.aspx)

Edit re comments

```
    string cs = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=z:\docs;";
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(cs);
    cn.Open();

    DataTable tables = cn.GetSchema("Tables");
    DataTable columns = cn.GetSchema("Columns");

    foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
    }
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: I get the columns from my two test "tables", that is, text files. See additional example.

Comment: @Fionualla: Is it possible to return the tables that their name contain a specific word?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to help the original poster but if it helps anyone else I made a mini project that goes through all the ODBC Tables and creates a class for each one with the column names as string fields. You can use these classes to compose string queries.

[Link to project](https://github.com/shanieMoonlight/Helpers)